# What is the purpose of a db context class in asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I'm new to MVC and have done some tutorials to get the hang of it, but in some of these tutorials I have come across an example with a DbContext class [asp.net mvc5 with EF6 tutorial](https://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/creating-an-entity-framework-data-model-for-an-asp-net-mvc-application)

I have tried researching information on DbContext Class but was unable to get any information that made me any the wiser! all I could find are more of the same tutorials with little information I also looked up the class on msdn [DbContext Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbcontext(v=VS.103).aspx).

I have done previous tutorials without a db context class and it works fine and my question is do I need to use a context class, and what are the advantages of using a DbContext Class?

Any help would be appreciated thanks.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74252487/7186739

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I would first say that the `DbContext` class relates to [Entity Framework (EF)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/ef.aspx), but then the question tags would suggest you figured that much out yourself. In typical usage, deriving from the `DbContext` class is simply *the way* to incorporate EF-based data access into your application. The class that derives from `DbContext` is, in essence, the data access layer of your application.

So to put it the other way around, if you want to do data access with Entity Framework, `DbContext` is what you want.

Answer (score 24):

You can think of `DbContext` as the database connection and a set of tables, and `DbSet` as a representation of the tables themselves. The `DbContext` allows you to link your model properties (presumably using the Entity Framework) to your database with a connection string.

Later, when you wish to refer to a database in your controller to handle data, you reference the `DbContext`. For Example,

```
public class UserSitesContext : DbContext
{
    public UserSitesContext()
        :base("name=UserSitesContext")
    {
    }

    public virtual DbSet<Site> Sites { get; set; }
}
```

is referenced later in the controller like

```
private UserSitesContext dbUser = new UserSitesContext();

var queryExample = from u in dbUser.Sites select u;
```

`:base("connection")` refers to your connection string found in `Web.config`.

Comment: does dbcontext creates new connection to db each time it is used?

Answer (score 3):

This is the base class responsible for managing database connections and provides  all sorts of DB related functionality like data access methods to interact with Database.

Answer (score 2):

DbContext is a class provided by Entity Framework to establish connection to database, query the db and close connection.

Extending DbContext permits to define database model with DbSet (specific Set mapped to a table or more), create a database, query a database...

Answer (score 1):

dbContext in Entityframework works like DAL Data Access Layer establish connection with your database.

Answer (score 0):

`DBContext` is a class in Entity Framework. Use to interact with database to perform database operation (select, insert, edit and delete) including Database connection.