# SQL to linq for Many to Many Relation (C# ASP.net MVC)

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I'm looking for some help to be able to transcript some LINQ from a SQL query :

Here is a quick look of my database :
[image: database schema]

Entity framework "simplify" my "etudiant" model like this :

```
[System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
public virtual ICollection<etuResult> etuResult { get; set; }

[System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
public virtual ICollection<cours> cours { get; set; }
```

I'm able to find the "libellé" of my "cours" where the "etudiant_id" == 1 in SQL like this :

```
select c.libelle
from cours c 
where c.cours_id in (
    select ec.cours_id
    from etuCours ec
    where ec.etudiant_id in (
        select e.etudiant_id
        from etudiant e
        ))
```

But i dont find how to make the query with linq (i use LinqPad 4 for my test)

Thanks for you help in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not call the collection directly on the entity? If it is mapped then the filtering happens automatically. No need to create another query.

```
var courses = myEtudiantInstance.cours;
```

If you want the `libelle` then

```
var libelles = myEtudiantInstance.cours.Select(c => c.libelle);
```

This requires either lazy loading to be enabled OR use `Include` when you get the  `Etudiant` instance on the collection.

```
var libelles = dbContextInstance.Etudiants
  .Include(e => e.cours)
  .Single(e => e.EtudiantId == 1) // will throw exception if entity not found
  .cours.Select(c => c.libelle); // get all libelle's
```

Comment: I didnt get everything on how you did it but you solved my problem !
Thanks, i will continue learning about this language :)

Answer (score 0):

Edit : in case this can be usefull to someone :

It's simpler to use a DAL folder (for Data Access Layer) as show on the [following](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/creating-an-entity-framework-data-model-for-an-asp-net-mvc-application)  tutorial (under the subtitle "Create the Database Context").

In case you don't understant what's the purpose on this folder, I suggest you [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31953317/what-is-the-purpose-of-a-db-context-class-in-asp-net-mvc) link.

If i made my MVC better and follow this tutorial, i wouldn't be in trouble for my Linq Queries